# Do I need to reply in this situation?

Tags: usage, nuances

(In a game) I am a newbie(Lv29), and I saw B(lv100+) having filled his room's wall with numerous super-super-rare(SSR) posters, which can be only be earned with enormous effort. (I don't have any)

I sent the below to him via messaging menu.

> I: スゴイ!

Later, I received the reply:

> B: どうかされましたか? (笑)

^I think it means "Is there anything wrong?"

Do I need to reply about why I thought him amazing?

Comment: Yes, in this situation I think he's expecting your further comment.

Comment: @broccoliforest Really? Maybe I'll need to give him late reply :)

Comment: Idk or maybe he's satisfied when you showed surprise. Anyway you can forget it if too much time has passed.

Comment: あなんたの多いSSRポスターだちを見て、私は本当に驚いていたと思います。

Comment: Sounds like he could guess what you were referring to as you say the amount of SSR he has is amazing, but I guess he kind of played dumb in a nice way and pretended he didn't know what you meant just to be humble. If you want to respond, you could also say something like `SSRポスターの数がすごいですね！` or `SSRポスターの数に驚きました！`